# Understanding the main purpose of creating Host in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

In IIS we need ASP.NET Core Module that hosts the app inside w3wp worker process.
Thinking the same was required for Kestrel, and apart from configuring logging, DI, and Middleware pipeline, the root purpose of `HostBuilder` is exactly the same i.e. to host the app inside Kestrel as ASP.NET Core module do to host the app inside IIS.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score -2):

You're *kind of* correct. You need to keep in mind that:

- You don't *have to* use IIS. You also need *something* to get the requests from IIS into your application, as the module inside IIS is only for making IIS aware of the ASP.NET Core pipeline, since IIS only works with ASP.NET (framework) natively. That extra setup, then, is needed both in IIS and ASP.NET Core (in the form of `UseIISIntegration`)
- ASP.NET Core needs to configure the middleware pipeline, services, etc etc.
- The idea behind modularizing like this is that you can easily remove `.UseIISIntegration()` and just host on Kestrel and even Kestrel behind other servers like nginx and httpd.
- The host doesn't know about Kestrel, only `Host.UseDefaultBuilder` (which calls `UseKestrel()` internally) inject Kestrel.

Basically, then, the Host is the central configuration of the app. Whether you use Kestrel, IIS, http.sys, or some other framework, is a decision of the particular app you might be working on.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So who host the app inside Kestrel ? and what does it mean when we say Host is responsible for the App startup?

Comment: @Bhavna Because the Host is what starts the ASP.NET Core app. A Console app is what "hosts" the ASP.NET Core app (all .NET applications are initially a Console app, except Windows services)

Comment: sir one last question, Host and web server these 2 terms really confuses me, if Console App hosts ASP.NET Core app then what does Kestrel do?

Comment: @Bhavna You can think of the Host as something "agnostic" to web, it doesn't need to host a web server. You can, through ASP.NET Core, add a web server to the host, but you don't *need to*. Kestrel is the library that handles HTTP requests and responses, TLS, certificates, so on and so forth

Comment: and this is really the last, haha, who can we term as Host for ASP.NET Framework? does IIS act as both host and web server there?

Comment: @Bhavna The Host is a new concept in ASP.NET Core (really in .NET Core), there's no real equivalent in ASP.NET Framework. You could say that a few classes compose the host in ASP.NET Framework (like Global.asax) but it's not really the same, and ASP.NET Framework *needs* IIS for operating, so perhaps IIS acts as both?